# Expected number of happy children

Tags: probability

This is a followup on [Arrangements of children](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/810747/arrangements-of-children).  (I am transcribing my notes, and making up problems to test my understanding and confirm their correctness)  I'll restate the set up.  $n$ children must be arranged in a row, but $k$ pairs of children will be unhappy unless they are together.  The others will always be happy.  If they are randomly arranged, is the expected number of happy children?

The game plan is to use linearity of expectation.  Let

$$ X_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if the $i$th child is happy} \\
                       0 & \text{otherwise}
         \end{cases}
$$

and let $F_i$ denote the event that the $i$th child is "fussy" -- he belongs to one of the pairs.  Then we have:

$$
 P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = 1|F_i')\cdot P(F_i') + P(X_i = 1|F_i)\cdot P(F_i)
$$

This expression holds in general.  But we have a boundary condition.  In particular,

$$P(X_1 = 1|F_1) = 1/n = P(X_n = 1 | F_n)$$

Since the $X_i$'s are indicators, we have $E(X_1|F_1) = \frac{n+1-2k}{n} = E(X_n|F_n)$.

For all the rest, we have $P(X_i = 1)  = E(X_i) = 1\cdot \frac{n-2k}{n} + \frac{2}{n}\cdot \frac{2k}{n}$

So it looks like

$$
  E(X) = \frac{2}{n} (n + 1 - 2k) + (n-2)\left(\frac{n-2k}{n} + \frac{4k}{n^2}\right)
$$

Is that correct?

Edit: Here is a write up of my first attempt,  which I thought was fallacious, but which got the same answer as André.

Let

$$X_i = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if the $i$th is happy} \\
                      0 & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
$$

We have

$$
P(X_i = 1) = P(X_i = 1|F_i')P(F_i') + P(X_i = 1|F_i)P(F_i) \\
           = 1 \cdot \frac{n-2k}{n} + \frac{2}{n}\frac{2k}{n}
$$

so that

$$
E(X) = n E(X_i) = n P(X_i = 1) = n - 2k + \frac{4k}{n}
$$

The mystery to me is that I basically sampled with replacement (and ignored the boundary) to get that $P(X_i = 1|F_i) = \frac{2}{n}$.

Comment: Let us do a careful evaluation of $\Pr(X_i=1|F_i)$. Child $i$ could be sitting in a non-end seat, and then the probability her friend sits next to her is $\frac{2}{n-1}$, or she could be in an end seat, in which case the probability is $\frac{1}{n-1}$. That gives probability $\frac{n-2}{n}\cdot \frac{2}{n-1}+\frac{2}{n}\cdot \frac{1}{n-1}$, which simplifies to $\frac{2}{n}$. So the $\frac{2}{n}$ is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $n-2k$ children who will be happy with probability $1$. We need to find the expected number of happy fussy children.

Divide the $2k$ fussy children into $k$ couples. Call these couples $1$ to $k$. Let $X_i=1$ if the two children in couple $i$ are happy, and let $X_i=0$ otherwise. We want $2E(\sum X_i)$, which is $2\sum E(X_i)$.

There are $\binom{n}{2}$ equally likely ways to choose the pair of spots occupied by couple $i$. Of these, $n-1$ are "favourable." Thus $\Pr(X_i=1)=\frac{2}{n}$.

It follows that the expected number of happy fussy children is $\frac{4k}{n}$. Add $n-2k$ to this.

Comment: Thanks André.  I got that answer on my first try, but I used a different (and I think fallacious method).  Can you take a look at that write up in a few minutes and comment?  Basically, the difference is I didn't mess about with the boundary.

Comment: Sure. I think separating out the $n-2k$ is useful, it lets us concentrate on the "variable" component.

Comment: I agree.  My argument is an artifact of how I write on paper.  I end up making a "table" of equations.  You can sort of see that the $1$ is below $P(X_i=1|F_i')$, $(n-2k)/n$ is below $P(F_i')$, etc, because they are equal.  It looks neater on paper though.

Comment: I have left a comment below your post, justifying your $\frac{2}{n}$. My solution had another justification of $\frac{2}{n}$.